# How can I write in a document with JavaScript and then download the document?

Tags: javascript, python, file, download

How can I write for example in a JSON or TXT file with JavaScript. After I write in the file how can I download it. Similar to doing this in python

```
File = open("FileToWriteIn.txt", "wb")
File.write("Hello")
File.close()
# Then I want to download the file which in this case would be FileToWriteIn.txt but I want to
# do this with JavaScript
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file saving take a look at [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which provides a simple approach to save files. Writing to a text file will then look like this:

```js
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

This will automatically open the download dialogue.

Comment: yo can filesaver.js be downloaded with npm

Comment: yes, check the bottom of the readme for further instructions: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#installation

Answer (score 0):

You can create Blobs,.  Below is an example, I've placed the result inside an iFrame for this snippet, but you could use window.open instead if you wanted to download.

```js
//create blob
const blob = 
  new Blob([JSON.stringify(
  {
    hello: 'world'
  })], 
  {type : 'application/json'});
  
//turn into a URL for download or view etc.
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

//for testing, lets put in an iframe
const frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.setAttribute('src',url);
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```